# Infinite sum of little o-p terms

Tags: probability-theory

This question seems painfully obvious, but I somehow can't convince myself. I have

$\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{a}_{n,i} (\hat{\mu}_{m_i,i} - \mu_i) $,

where

- $\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{a}_{n,i} = 1$ (I have a weighted average of the $\mu$ terms)
- As $m_i \rightarrow \infty$, $(\hat{\mu}_{m_i,i} - \mu_i) = o_p(1)$, $i=1,...,n$.

I'm interested in studying this sum as $n, m_i \rightarrow \infty$. Is it OK to write this as

$\sum_{i=1}^n \hat{a}_{n,i} (\hat{\mu}_{m_i,i} - \mu_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n ( \hat{a}_{n,i} o_p(1) ) = o_p(1)$,

since the $o_p(1)$-ness of $(\hat{\mu}_{m_i,i} - \mu_i)$ is independent of $i$ and $n$?

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: $X_n = o_P(1)$ means that $X_n \to_\mathbb{P} 0$ as $n \to \infty$. When you write $o_P(1)$, there always is *some* random variable it refers to. In order for your question to make sense, you would need to write it in terms of that random variable. It can currently be interpreted in several ways, possibly yielding different answers.

Comment: If $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$ for all $n$ then $a_1 = 1$ and $a_i = 0$ for $i>1$. Are you sure that's the condition you want?

Comment: Thanks very much for these comments. I've tried to clarify things.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Pointwise consistency for each $i$ is not enough. You need $max_i(\hat{μ}_{m_i,i}−μ_i)^2 \to o_p(1)$ (uniform consistency).

Also, you should restrict the weights so that $\sum^n_{i=1} |\hat{a}_{n,i}| = Op(1)$, otherwise you could have $|\hat{a}_{n,i}| \to \infty$ for a $i$, say. The condition is automatically satisfied for non-negative $\hat{a}_{n,i}$.

If both conditions are satisfied you get

$\sum^n_{i=1} \hat{a}_{n,i}(\hat{μ}_{m_i,i}−μ_i)^2 \le max_i(\hat{μ}_{m_i,i}−μ_i)^2 \times  \sum^n_{i=1} |\hat{a}_{n,i}| = o_p(1)$