# Using uniform convergence to show the joint limit of a double-indexed sum

Tags: probability, limits, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, uniform-convergence

Thanks for opening this question which has bothered me for a while.

Given random variables $e_{it}$ and $a_i$ for $i=1,...,N$ and $t=1,...,T$ with the following properties:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T e_{it} &= o_p(1) \ \ \forall i\in{1,...,N}\\
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N |a_i| &= O_p(1)
\end{align}
WTS
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{NT}\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{t=1}^Te_{it}a_i \stackrel{p}{\to} 0\ \ as \ \ N,T\to\infty \ \ jointly 
\end{align}

Attempt:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{NT}\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{t=1}^Te_{it}a_i & \leq \frac{1}{NT}\sum_{i=1}^N \sup_{i\in {1,...,N}} \left\{\left|\sum_{t=1}^Te_{it} \right|\right\} \left|a_i\right| \\
& = \sup_{i\in {1,...,N}}\left\{\left|\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^Te_{it} \right|\right\}  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \left|a_i\right|
\end{align}

It seems like I need uniform convergence like
\begin{align}
 \sup_{i\in\{1,...,N\}} \left| \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^Te_{it} \right| \stackrel{p}{\to} 0 \ \ as \ \ N,T \to \infty \ \ jointly
\end{align}
However, I can't prove the uniform convergence since $i\in\{1,2,...\}$ is not compact.
(The theorem is here: [Uniform consistency of a sum of functions with random weights?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825853/uniform-consistency-of-a-sum-of-functions-with-random-weights))

Is there anyway to show it? Some additional information may be useful but I am not sure how to use: ($a_i$ are i.i.d across $i$, $e_{it}$ and $e_{jt}$ are not correlated for $i\ne j$).

(A related question: [Infinite sum of little o-p terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965553/infinite-sum-of-little-o-p-terms))

I really appreciate it if you have any thoughts! Thanks a lot!